# java code not showing results without resizing frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to remodel a phone keypad, however I cannot see the results without resizing the results window, which I dont want.

here is my code:
the code would run just fine before I entered the code for the display area. but after that, I have to continuously resize it(which I dont want) ive tried resizing the display area itself.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class mobilePhone{

    private JFrame keypadFrame;
    private JPanel panels1;
    private JTextArea displayArea;

    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton b5;
    private JButton b6;
    private JButton b7;
    private JButton b8;
    private JButton b9;
    private JButton b10;
    private JButton b11;
    private JButton b12;
    private JButton b13;
    private JButton b14;
    private JButton b15;

    public mobilePhone(){
        Interface();
    }
    public void Interface(){

        keypadFrame = new JFrame("Mobile Calculator");
        keypadFrame.setVisible(true);
        keypadFrame.setSize(270, 300);
        keypadFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        keypadFrame.setResizable(false);

        displayArea = new JTextArea(2,5);
        displayArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Border DABorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,4);
        displayArea.setBorder(DABorder);
        Font DAFont = new Font("ariel",Font.BOLD,30);
        displayArea.setFont(DAFont);
        displayArea.setLineWrap(true);

        panels1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
        panels1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        Border panelBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE,5);
        panels1.setBorder(panelBorder); 

        b1 = new JButton("7");
        b2 = new JButton("8");
        b3 = new JButton("9");
        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b7 = new JButton("1");
        b8 = new JButton("2");
        b9 = new JButton("3");
        b10 = new JButton("*");
        b11 = new JButton("0");
        b12 = new JButton("#");
        b13 = new JButton("CLEAR");

        panels1.add(b1);
        panels1.add(b2);
        panels1.add(b3);
        panels1.add(b4);
        panels1.add(b5);
        panels1.add(b6);
        panels1.add(b7);
        panels1.add(b8);
        panels1.add(b9);
        panels1.add(b10);
        panels1.add(b11);
        panels1.add(b12);

        keypadFrame.add(panels1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        keypadFrame.add(displayArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        keypadFrame.add(b13, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new mobilePhone();

    }
}
```

Comment: `Font DAFont = new Font("ariel",Font.BOLD,30);` "ariel" is a mermaid & "Arial" is only installed on certain machines. Better to use `Font.SANS_SERIF` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `keypadFrame.setVisible(true);` and place it at the end of your `Interface` method (and then have a look at [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others)

Alternatively, call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the frame's `contentPane`

Comment: *"Take `keypadFrame.setVisible(true);` and place it at the end of your `Interface` method"*  Put `keypadFrame.pack();` immediately before that call to ensure the GUI is the right size. Then remove the guesswork inherent in `keypadFrame.setSize(270, 300);` ..